# With Gitkit, how to verify the email address of users who register with a password?

Tags: java, email-verification, google-identity-toolkit

The Google Identity Toolkit (Gitkit) documenation still has a patchy coverage of topics. One of the cases which doesn't have proper documentation is the verification of email addresses of users who create a password account instead of signing in with an Identity Provider.

I did find a method `public String getEmailVerificationLink(String email)` in the [Java library](https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-java-client) for Gitkit but there is no description for this method. Upon running this method, I found that besides returning a user specific verification link, it also triggered a verification mail to this email address. Sometimes, this method also returns an error: `org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["oobCode"] not found`.

So the question is: how is this method supposed to be used and are there any other steps / checks that are required in the email verification process? For example, do we need to separately check whether an email address has already been verified before calling this method?

**Gitkit team**, besides answering this question, it would be really helpful if you could please plug other gaps in the documentation of both the Gitkit API and the client libraries. An example of another topic that is not yet covered is the control over password requirements: how can we customize the password strength requirements and communicate them to users on the sign up page?

Answer (score 3):

In the [Google Identity Toolkit IdToken](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/required-endpoints#decoding_the_identity_toolkit_id_token), there is a field `verified`. If it is false, that means the email of the user has not been verified.

When your server wants to verify a user's email, call `getEmailVerificationLink(email)` to get back a one-time verification url from Identity Toolkit server. The URL should point to the Identity Toolkit widget page, with a one-time code in the query param.

Your server then sends an email, containing the url, to the address. Once the user clicks the url, the Identity Toolkit widget will handle the remaining steps (validate the one time code, mark the verified flag in storage), and redirect the browser to the SignInSuccessUrl.

The password strength is not customizable in the current SDK. We are working on that.

Comment: Thanks! Does the Gitkit Java client library contain a method to read the ID token fields directly or would we need to use an external library for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, the Gitkit java library provides the validateTokenToJson() method to validate a token and return all fields in the token payload, including the 'verified' field. https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/identitytoolkit/GitkitClient.java#L165